# Embedding hyperlinks in Snowflake table fields

Tags: hyperlink, uri, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to house a clickable URI inside a table row & field in Snowflake?

Example: Table product_master w fields product_name, prod_num, prod_family, prod_price, prod_brochure where prod_brochure is a clickable URI to the slick brochure that can be printed out.

Comment: If you want to store the full HTML that goes along with the hyperlink, you certainly can.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Sort of.  I know I can store the URI as a regular text string - my question is can I store it as an active hyperlink?

Comment: Yes you can. As Mike has mentioned you should store the full HTML as a string. Whether the link is "clickable" or not depends on the tool that renders it, not how it is stored in the datbase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your browser (or wherever you're viewing your Snowflake results) supports making the VARCHAR/text link clickable, as Simon D mentions. Here's a Snowflake query snippet where I make a link from an id column to link to a Salesforce object. Google Chrome automatically makes it clickable in the Snowflake query results using the classic Snowflake worksheet interface:

```
  SELECT 'https://mycompany.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/SF_custom_object_c/' || id || '/view' AS sf_job_link, ...
```

The results in a Snowflake web UI/Chrome clickable link:
[image]